# Can't see product even in Backoffice after added product via C# SOAP V2 Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I am trying to add a product in C# with SOAP V2 here is my code :

```
PortTypeClient ptc = new PortTypeClient();

string sessionId = ptc.login("dev", "123456789");
        catalogProductCreateEntity np = new catalogProductCreateEntity();
        np.name = "My new product";
        np.description = "my description";
        np.status = "1";
        np.price = "10.00";

        np.category_ids = new string[] { "8"};
        int a = ptc.catalogProductCreate(sessionId, "simple", "9","mysku1", np, "1");
```

I get a returned value a which is the entity_id in the catalog_product_entity table, i can see the entry in that table, but it is not showing up in the backoffice (even after I flushed Magento Cache and Cache Storage)

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I got it to work, i went to the back office to see which fileds were mandatory, especially the visibility field which i forgot.

```
     PortTypeClient ptc = new PortTypeClient();
        filters filters = new filters();
        string sessionId = ptc.login("dev", "123456789");

        catalogProductCreateEntity np = new catalogProductCreateEntity();
        np.name = "My new product";
        np.description = "my description";
        np.status = "1";
        np.price = "10.00";
        np.tax_class_id = "1";
        np.weight = "0";
        np.visibility = "4";

        np.category_ids = new string[] { "8" };

        int a = ptc.catalogProductCreate(sessionId, "simple", "9", "mysku", np, "1");
```

However i haven't created the product with an image here. This is just the bare minimum. I learnt a lot about the different entities at your disposal by pulling some entities with methods such as salesOrderList,catalogProductInfo or catalogProductList.